# Why can an NPM module's dependency be always installed to nested node_modules?

Tags: npm, protractor, node-modules

As you know, NPM v3 tries to keep the dependency tree as flat as possible. Previously I thought it installs dependencies as nested only to solve conflicts in case there is more than one version of the same module.

However, I've noticed something strange about the module `protractor`. It has a dependency, `webdriver-manager`, which is always installed as nested, to `node_modules/protractor/node_modules`. You can easily reproduce this by running `npm install protractor` in an empty folder.

Why does this happen?

Comment: Perhaps it's related to that module's use in the `bin` configuration?

Comment: Most likely you're right, but I'd like to understand the details, how exactly this works. Seems like it's something not really documented.

Comment: There's a related, open [issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/11466), so it's unclear as to whether or not the non-flattening is the intended behaviour. Who knows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats a great question and the current behavior is expected. `npmV3` indeed installs dependencies in flat structure and `Protractor` is also installed the same way

When Protractor is installed with `npmV3`

[image]

When Protractor is installed with `npmV2.*`

[image]

All modules are installed in Flat Structure except that still `webdriver-manager` is still in nested structure. And this is because of conflicting dependencies.

[As per official documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/how-npm-works/npm3)

> Your dependencies will now be installed maximally flat. Insofar as is
>   possible, all of your dependencies, and their dependencies, and THEIR
>   dependencies will be installed in your project's node_modules folder
>   with no nesting. You'll only see modules nested underneath one another
>   when two (or more) modules have conflicting dependencies.
>
> Now, let's say we want to require another module, C. C requires B, but
>   at another version than A.However, since B v1.0 is already a top-level
>   dep, we cannot install B v2.0 as a top level dependency. npm v3
>   handles this by defaulting to npm v2 behavior and nesting the new,
>   different, module B version dependency under the module that requires
>   it -- in this case, module C.

`webdriver-manager package.json` lists dependencies `"minimist": "^1.2.0",`, which is in conflict requirements of other packages like optimist which needs the below dependency list

```
  ├─ optimist@0.6.1
   │  ├─ wordwrap@0.0.3
   │  └─ minimist@0.0.10
```

Hence due to conflicting dependencies, `webdriver-manager` is installed inside `protractor node_modules`

Do a `npm-remote-ls protractor` for complete dependency tree and conflicts across all dependencies

Comment: Thanks for solving this mystery.